# Reading data from a json file in Android and put it in an array

Tags: android, json, file

if i have a json file like that

```
{
"users": [{
        "name": "aa",
        "address": "a"
    },
    {
        "name ": "bb",
        "address": "b"
    },
    {
        "name": "cc",
        "address": "c"
    },

]}
```

how to read this json file and put all names in a String array in android

i used this code but in second loop it catches exception

```
public void loadJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("data.json");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray m_jArry = obj.getJSONArray("users");

        for (int i = 0; i < m_jArry.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jo_inside = m_jArry.getJSONObject(i);
            names.add(jo_inside.getString("name"));
            images.add(jo_inside.getString("address"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: post the exception....log

Comment: Post exception stack trace.

Comment: No value for name @rafsanahmad007

Answer (score 2):

That Json object 2nd element in the array has space next to name you can solve by 2 ways.

- 1. As your backend guys to change that
- 2. You solve the problem like this,

Change getString to optString like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_jArry.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jo_inside = m_jArry.getJSONObject(i);

            String name = jo_inside.optString("name");

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
                name = jo_inside.optString("name "); // that object have space
            }
        names.add(name);
        images.add(jo_inside.getString("address"));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Json` file contain wrong format JSON.

Remove `,` from the last array element

```
    {
        "name": "cc",
        "address": "c"
    },
```

The valid Json should be:

```
 {
    "users": [{
            "name": "aa",
            "address": "a"
        },
        {
            "name": "bb",
            "address": "b"
        },
        {
            "name": "cc",
            "address": "c"
        }

    ]
}
```

Comment: happy to help...if the answer works you are welcome to mark it as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have problem in your JSON string only. In second JSON `name` field has extra space. And also there is `,` after last JSON `},`

```
{
    "users": [{
            "name":"aa",
            "address":"a"
        },
        {
            "name":"bb",
            "address":"b"
        },
        {
            "name":"cc",
            "address":"c"
        }
    ]
}
```